# How can I remove the "Add an Owner" button from the representative side?

Tags: c#, .net, razor-pages

I would like to remove the "Add an Owner" button from the Representative side of my form, struggling to figure out how. I have narrowed it down to - this line i think - @if (Model is Farm Owner && Owner != null)

```
@if (update)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col d-grid gap-4 text-end align-self-end mt-3 me-3 ms-3 mb-3">
            @if (Model is Farm Owner && Owner != null)
            { 
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-3 ms-3 ps-2 pb-1 pe-2 pt-1" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" asp-route-Id="@((Farm)Model).Id" asp-action="AddOwner">@Lang["Add an Owner"]</button>
            }
            else
            {
                <button disabled type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-3 ms-3 ps-2 pb-1 pe-2 pt-1" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" asp-action="AddOwner">@Lang["Add an Owner"]</button>
            }
            @if (Model is Farm)
            {
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-3 ms-3 ps-2 pb-1 pe-2 pt-1" asp-action="Save">@Lang["Save"]</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-3 ms-3 ps-2 pb-1 pe-2 pt-1" asp-action="Submit">@Lang["Submit For Review"]</button>
            }
            @if (Model is Owner)
            {
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-3 ms-3 ps-2 pb-1 pe-2 pt-1" asp-action="SaveOwner">@Lang["Save"]</button> 
            }
            @if (Model is Representative Representative && Representative.Id != null)
            {
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-3 ms-3 ps-2 pb-1 pe-2 pt-1" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" asp-route-Id="@((Representative)Model).Id" asp-action="AddRep">@Lang["Add a Representative"]</button>
            }
            @if (Model is Representative)
            {
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-3 ms-3 ps-2 pb-1 pe-2 pt-1" asp-action="AddRep">@Lang["Save"]</button>
            }
            @if (newEntity)
            {
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-3 ms-3 ps-2 pb-1 pe-2 pt-1" asp-action="Add" formnovalidate="formnovalidate">@Lang["Reset"]</button>   
            }
            else
            {
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-3 ms-3 ps-2 pb-1 pe-2 pt-1" asp-action="ShowDetails" formnovalidate="formnovalidate">@Lang["Reset"]</button>
            }
            
            @if (delete)
            {
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary me-3 ms-3 ps-2 pb-1 pe-2 pt-1" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" asp-action="Delete" data-prompt="Are you sure you want to Delete the record?">@Lang["Delete"]</button>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the button you have to remove the complete if/else statement.

```cs
@if (!(Model is Representative Representative && Representative.Id != null))
{
  @if (Model is Farm Owner && Owner != null)
  { 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-3 ms-3 ps-2 pb-1 pe-2 pt-1" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" asp-route-Id="@((Farm)Model).Id" asp-action="AddOwner">@Lang["Add an Owner"]</button>
  }
  else
  {
    <button disabled type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-3 ms-3 ps-2 pb-1 pe-2 pt-1" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" asp-action="AddOwner">@Lang["Add an Owner"]</button>
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to keep it on the side where the user adds a Farm, once the Farm is created the button for "Add an Owner" is enabled, just no need for it on the Representative (of the farm) side

Comment: Ok, then wrap the first if in another if - I'll update my answer.

Comment: that didnt work.

Comment: now the "Add an Owner" is not on the Credit/Manage/Add side and its not on the Credit/Manage/Addrep side

Comment: As long as you don't provide more details about your site I'm afraid I can't help you any better

Comment: what do you need?

Answer (score 0):

```
            @if (Model is Representative)
            {
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-3 ms-3 ps-2 pb-1 pe-2 pt-1" asp-action="AddRep">@Lang["Save"]</button>
            }
            else @if (Model is Farm owner && owner.Id != null)
            { 
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-3 ms-3 ps-2 pb-1 pe-2 pt-1" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" asp-route-Id="@((Farm)Model).Id" asp-action="AddOwner">@Lang["Add an Owner"]</button>
            }
            else
            {
                <button disabled type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-3 ms-3 ps-2 pb-1 pe-2 pt-1" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" asp-action="AddOwner">@Lang["Add an Owner"]</button>
            }
```

Comment: that did the trick